# How to compare 2 sets of arrays for distinct matches

Tags: c#, arrays, algorithm, linq

Given I have 4 arrays of integers: (I'll call these the master arrays)

And I also have x number of separate integer arrays: (Call these the data arrays)

I want to be able to work out how many of the data arrays I have where at least one of their entries is also in one of the 4 master arrays but where a master array can only be used once.

I am after a solution in C# ideally but pseudo code will suffice.

**Some Examples:**

Given the master arrays:

```
[1],
[2, 3],
[4, 5, 6, 7],
[8]
```

with data arrays:

```
[1],
[2],
[3, 9]
```

The result should be 2.

- Data array 1 matched with Master 1.
- Data array 2 matches with Master 2.
- Data array 3 matches with Master 2 (but Master 2 has already been used).

with data arrays:

```
[1],
[2, 8]
[2],
[9]
```

The result should be 3.

- Data array 1 matched with Master 1.
- Data array 2 matches with Master 2 & 4 (should only count once but later entries will decide which one to use).
- Data array 3 matches with Master 2 (2 was matched above but so was 4).
- Data array 4 doesn't match

Answer (score 2):

It seems quite simple:

```
var masters = new[]
{
    new[] { 1 },
    new[] { 2, 3 },
    new[] { 4, 5, 6, 7 },
    new[] { 8 }
};

var data = new[] 
{
    new[] { 1 },
    new[] { 3, 9 },
    new[] { 2 },
};

// Has masters[i] already been "consumed"?
var used = new bool[masters.Length];

// The found indexes in masters. -1 if not found/already used
var res = new int[data.Length];

for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
{
    // The default condition is "not found"
    res[i] = -1;

    for (int j = 0; j < masters.Length; j++)
    {
        // If masters[j] already used/consumed, then skip it
        if (used[j])
        {
            continue;
        }

        // We are looking for an intersection between masters[j] and data[i]
        if (masters[j].Intersect(data[i]).Any())
        {
            used[j] = true;
            res[i] = j;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can simply

```
int count = res.Count(x => x != -1);
```

Note that this algorithm has a complexity "in time" of O(n^2) (something like `O(master.Length * data.Length)` or `O(n^3)` if we consider the medium length of `data[x].Length`.

Comment: Sorry, but `int[][] data = new [] {new [] { 8, 2 }, new [] { 1 }, new [] { 2 },new [] { 9 }};` is a *counter example*. Expected: **3**, Actual: **2** (unless *greedy* algorithm *must* be used)

Comment: Would you not get the count from doing used.Count(c => c)?

Comment: @CeejeeB Because I'm saving the `-1` as "failure"

Comment: @DmitryBychenko It is a first come first-served. `data[0]` uses `master[1]` because it is the first non-used master.

Comment: First come first served doesn't answer the question. In @DmitryBychenko answer it must return 3

Comment: @CeejeeB No: data[0] => master[1], data[1] => master[0], data[2] => master[1] but already used so skipped, data[3] => not found. Count = 2. But I don't "maximize" the response "reordering" the `data`. For me `data` and `master` are ordered. First matched, first serverd/used. You probably don't see it because he deleted his response, but his incipit was *If you are looking for a efficient (we use as many data arrays as possible) master arrays assigning:*

Comment: @xanatos I am sorry my question wasn't clear enough i have edited the second example. No arrays are ordered so this is incorrect.

Comment: @CeejeeB Then it is a totally different problem, because it becomes a knapsack problem.

Answer (score 2):

I'm sorry for my premature answer, I've rewritten it from scratch. We have a well known *graph problem*, **Maximum Bipartite Matching** to be exact. Where

- **Part 1 vertexes**: `master` arrays
- **Part 2 vertexes**: `data` arrays
- **Edge**: if data array share at least one item with master array (intersection is not empty)

Having this done you can solve the problem as

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/maximum-bipartite-matching/

https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~ckingsf/bioinfo-lectures/matching.pdf

Comment: if dataArrays just contained a single array [1,2] this would return 2 when it should return 1

Comment: @CeejeeB: You are absolutely true, it's a *counter example*. Shame on me for not found the well known graph problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is not the PERFECT solution but it works

```
        int[,] master = new int[4,4];
        master[0,0]=1;
        master[1,0]=2;
        master[1,1]=3;
        master[2,0]=4;
        master[2,1]=5;
        master[2,2]=6;
        master[2,3]=7;
        master[3,0]=8;
        int[,] data = new int[3,2];
        data[0,0]=1;
        data[1,0]=2;
        data[2,0]=3;
        data[2,1]=9;

        bool [] usedmaster= new bool[4];
        for (int i=0;i<4;i++) usedmaster[i]=false;    

        for (int di=0;di<3;di++)
        {
            for (int dj=0;dj<2;dj++)
            {
                if (data[di,dj]>0)
                {
                    int mi=0,mj=0,k=0;
                    foreach (int n in master)
                    {
                        if (data[di,dj]==n)
                        {
                            string ss="";

                                if (usedmaster[k]==true) ss="{but master "+(k).ToString()+ " used}";

                            Console.WriteLine("Data array "+(di).ToString()+" matched with master "+(k).ToString()+ss);
                            usedmaster[k]=true;
                            k+=1;

                            break;
                        }
                        mj +=1;
                        if (master[mi,mj]==0) 
                        {
                            k +=1;
                            mi +=1;
                            mj=0;
                        }
                        if (mj>3) 
                        {
                            mj=0;
                            mi +=1;  
                            k +=1;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```